# Running SonarQube on Hybris Custom Extensions

Tags: sonarqube, sap-commerce-cloud

In Hybris, running **"ant alltests"** of platform/build.xml generates an HTML report of test cases execution.

Running **"ant sonar"** of platform/build.xml results in analysis report, 
But Junit/testcase coverage is not being shown.

For Sonar to check coverage, do we need any extra configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the *jacoco* ant target first :

> ant jacocoalltests

Comment: I finally found this target in acceleratorservices's acc-ant-sonar. xml file, and could call it from platform directory. I had to pass extension list using - Dtestclasses.extensions

Comment: I face this error while feeding jacoco report generating using above solution to Sonar: 
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xc0 (at char #1, byte #-1)

Comment: is there any way to run webtests and alltests at once, (together) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the analysis where to find the unit test reports. It's not clear from your question which engine you're using, but [the docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project) should help you figure out which property names to use.